# UICollectionViewCell with 2 cells, every single cell with "wrap_content" height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to have a automatic-height cells on a CollectionView.

I have 2 different cells, that works.

When I rotate the device `landscape`, I change to automatic height and width. It works. But when getting back to `portrait`, it does not:

```
func checkEstimatedSize(){
    if(DeviceType.IS_IPAD || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight){
        if let layout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
            layout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }else{
        if(UIDevice.current.orientation == .portrait || UIDevice.current.orientation == .portraitUpsideDown){
            if let layout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                //get width of CollectionView
                layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
                layout.invalidateLayout()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When portrait, I want width same as CollectionView but height depends on the content of the cell.

I know there is a `sizeForItemAt indexPath`, but how to check/set "autoheight" to a cell (or CollectionView).

Sorry, I am not an expert, that's why I am asking experts...

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

turns out that I changed `layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: myCollectionView.frame.width, height: 0)` on the second else and kinda works...
but now I am receiving a warning plus simulator freeze:
`The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
MyApp the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.`

ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize` to my else:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){
    checkEstimatedSize()
}

func checkEstimatedSize(){
    if(DeviceType.IS_IPAD || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight){
        if let layout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
            layout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }else{
        if let layout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
            layout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }
}
```

Like this works perfectly!

Thank you all!